# How can we setup the services in my EC2 instance to startup automatically on boot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux

When ever I restart my EC2 instance I have to manually use the command `systemctl start <service name >` to start the service.

Is there any option to automate this thing in the Linux platform?

Comment: `systemctl enable <service name>`

Comment: @jayhendren Thanks for the simple and straight answer this worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of articles online regarding this, but here is one that should be simple enough => [Link](https://timleland.com/how-to-run-a-linux-program-on-startup/)